# MySQL UPDATE changes value to '0' instead of the provided integer when using bind_param

Tags: php, mysqli

Using AJAX I try to update table 'forminfo' in a MySQL database, calling the php script via GET and providing an id (integer value). However, when I call changeRequestedQ.php?id=4 for instance, the table cell will update to 0, not 4.

The column 'requestedQ' is formatted as INT(11). When I try to update `$id = 4` manually, it works and the table cell is updated to 4.

```
require_once("msqli_config.php");

$id = $_GET['id']; // doesn't work, table cell updates to 0, whatever integer value I pass through file.php?id=<int>
$id = (int)$_GET['id']; // no change in outcome
$id = 4; // works, table cell updates to 4

try {
    $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE forminfo SET requestedQ = ? WHERE id = 1;");
    $stmt1->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt1->execute();
    $stmt1->close();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e);
    exit();
}

$mysqli->close();
```

I have tried forcing PHP to parse the value as integer using `(int)$_GET['id']`, but there was no difference.

Additional variations (not using prepared statements):

```
$sql = "UPDATE forminfo SET requestedQ = '4' WHERE id = 1";
$mysqli->query($sql); // updates to 4
echo $sql; // UPDATE forminfo SET requestedQ = '4' WHERE id = 1

$sql = "UPDATE forminfo SET requestedQ = 4 WHERE id = 1";
$mysqli->query($sql); // updates to 4
echo $sql; // UPDATE forminfo SET requestedQ = 4 WHERE id = 1

$sql = "UPDATE forminfo SET requestedQ = '" . $id . "' WHERE id = 1";
$mysqli->query($sql); // updates to 0
echo $sql; // UPDATE forminfo SET requestedQ = '4' WHERE id = 1

$sql = "UPDATE forminfo SET requestedQ = " . $id . " WHERE id = 1";
$mysqli->query($sql); // updates to 0
echo $sql; // UPDATE forminfo SET requestedQ = 4 WHERE id = 1
```

**UPDATE**
Being desperate, as I couldn't get my head around the difference in result between the previously mentioned pieces of code, I tried if this might be a specific browser issue. It turnes out that the above code works like a charm in MS Edge, and also in Google Chrome in Incognito mode, just not in a normal session. How can this be? Does it have to do with caching? I disabled cache in developers tools, but this didn't help...

Comment: Did you try to var_dump your `$_GET`?

Comment: Yes, it will return ```array(1) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
}``` as expected

Comment: Can you try `$stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE forminfo SET requestedQ = " . $id . " WHERE id = 1;"); //$stmt1->bind_param("i", $id);` just to rule out the binding as the issue.

Comment: @user3783243 Tried this, no change

Comment: So it is definitely something with the `$id` variable. Is there code between the assignment, your `var_dump`, and the query execution? `$id` being reassigned to a string is the only thing I could see.

Comment: @user3783243 No, this is literally all the code there is. If I do ```var_dump($id)``` I get ```int(4)```. But even if it would be reassigned to a string, PHP would convert it to an integer anyway, right?

Comment: If it were an integer string yes. If it were set to `myid5` though it would not.

Comment: Is the page containing this code ever accessed without `?id=xx` in the URL?

Comment: @user3783243 of course, I've tested everything with integers strings

Comment: @rickdenhaan never. Getting headaches from this issue.

Comment: You want bind_value()

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Is there a `bind_value` with `mysqli`? I can't find it in the docs.. I'm also not clear why that would be needed the `$id` should work as a parameter, no?

Comment: @user3783243 See my updated question

Comment: @user2576247 Sorry, I guess I had PDO in mind. Also, that would explain why `$id = (int)$_GET['id']` doesn't work but not why `$id = $_GET['id']` doesn't either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem. Thinking that this was a PHP/MySQL thing, I never looked into my browsers behaviour, nor the request and response parameters. My bad...

It turnes out that a browser plugin in Chrome was sending a second empty GET request (so without the query string) to the same destination, after the original request finished loading. Withoud `$_GET['id']` defined, the table cell updates to 0. Removed the plugin, everything works.

Comment: In that case a good idea would be wrapping this whole thing in `if(!empty($_GET['id'])) {` then it will only execute when you have an `id`.

Comment: @user3783243 I added ```if (!isset($_GET['id'])) exit("No id provided");```, which is good practice indeed.